# Norton 360 watermark issue

Tags: norton-360

[The watermarks in the bottom right of every icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvBbx.png) are incredibly annoying and I just want to know how to get rid of them. I have no experience in this and I have no idea how to fix it. I've googled tons of things, but I guess I just don't know the right terminology. If anyone could help me to remove these that would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Open N360, click settings, un-check backup status overlays on the right hand side.* (from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/140908-need-help-remove-blue-icon.html#post1210224) )

Comment: OMG thank you!! I never would have guessed that, the symbol honestly looks so much like powershell to me and only showed up after I was messing around with it. Thanks a bunch :)